On 24.04 setting waylandEnable=false does not work, still uses Wayland, I want to use Xorg
Basically what's in the title, I don't have the option to pick either Xorg or Wayland at login and the commonly cited fix to uncomment this line in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf does not work:
[~]$ cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf | grep Wayland
WaylandEnable=false

I then log out, log back in and I'm still on Wayland:
[~]$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

On reboot, I just get a blank screen since presumably I've disabled the only means of running graphics on my laptop.
I've installed everything I can think of that should include Xorg:

[~]$ sudo apt install xorg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
xorg is already the newest version (1:7.7+23ubuntu3).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 16 not to upgrade.
[~]$ sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.539).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 16 not to upgrade.
[~]$ 

What can I do to switch to Xorg?

Dropped into one of the virtual consoles (think ctrl-alt-f6) and from there ran sudo startx. That spat out some stuff about there being a typo in my X11  conf file (/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf), I corrected it, disabled Wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf again, and now I get the cog in the bottom right corner, letting me pick Xorg (called just "Ubuntu").
Definitely recommend running startx in a non-windowed, console-only session and just resolving any issues that throws up.

I tried your approach and I have nothing in my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder. And I did not succeed in getting xorg server running. Now I'm stuck with Wayland and my chrome looks blurry. I regret upgrading to 24.04. Now I consider reinstalling my whole system to a different distribution or just Ubuntu 22.04.

I did have these files in my case, I suspect I ran something that set them up, can't exactly remember, it's a slog getting it to work, but it's doable, and I agree 24.04 is very poorly rolled out, Wayland is just not ready

Does this help? https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/rejvf6/please_clarify_what_the_archwiki_is_telling_to_do/

running startx in the console pointed to the issue in the config file!
thank you for the perfect tip!
